# Avoid entity duplication with Linq in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to know the best way of avoiding entity duplication in an ASP.NET Core Web API project.

Imagine that you have a product with a name and manufacturer and you want to make sure if the name is not duplicated. Imagine that a new product with a name came from client (dto) and we need to look if the name (entity) already exists in the database (using EF).

1. You need to trim the name (`name.trim()`) for both names from entity and dto
2. You need to remove all the whitespaces in between (`string.replace(" ", string.empty())`
3. You need to change everything to lower case (`string.lower()`)
4. Finally you need to compare these two

Is there any best practices how to do this without writing all the code? I tried to use `string.compare` with the `compareoptions` like `ignorecase` and `ignoresymbols` and also the `string.equal()` with `ignorecase` option but the EF gives me an alarm that it can not translate the code.

br

Comment: Basically, there's no build-in method for your comparison scenario. You need to write business logic for your requirement such as write an extension method for string.

Comment: @TinyWang : writing an extension method is quite a good scenario , but i always get an error from EF that says it can not be translated .

Comment: share your code snippet and error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for your approach.

1. Introduce another column (This can be a primary key with other keys) and save the name with trimming and lowercase when you insert a new record to that table.

Example:
Original Name : Amir Masoud Babaei -->
New Column value: amirmasoudbabaei

2. And when you insert a new record, do your trimming and lowercase changes and save it to the database. Since it is a primary key, it should throw an error.
3. So with this approach, you don't need to loop through all the names and validate if the name is already exist.

Comment: Thanks Avi , this scenario is really cool but we do have quite other business logics that has also be in concern . like the Serial number is also needed to be unique or other logics . so , i think it is not a good idea that i made a column for each business logic , right ?

Comment: Absolutely correct, we do NOT need to create separate columns for each and every validations you are gonna perform. So in that case, you can define an interface called IValidation and it has only one method called Validate().  So you can implement this in your concrete classes and do perform the validations for each and every properties you want. This is more cleaner and nice.